# Aggregate SQL Query, GROUP BY Causing Issues

Tags: sql

Everything in this query works except for the second LEFT JOIN, where BEGIN_DATE and END_DATE are. Because I have to group by the additional columns, so they can be used in the "on join", I am getting false numbers. Is there any way to do this without having to group by. I hope this makes sense. Basically because I have to include BEGIN_DATE AND END_DATE in the group by, everything gets lost.

```
SELECT 
    to_char(T1.CALL_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-IW') AS OMONTH
    ,COUNT(T1.HOUSE) AS NODECALLS
    ,T3.NODE_CODE
    ,T5.NODECUSTCOUNT
    ,T1.CALL_CATEGORY_LVL_3
    ,sum((CASE WHEN T1.TC_WIP_TRANSACTION_ID IS NOT NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )) AS TC
    ,sum((CASE WHEN T1.TC_WIP_TRANSACTION_ID IS NOT NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ))/nullif(COUNT(T1.HOUSE), 0)    AS SVRATEPERCALL
    ,COUNT(T1.HOUSE)/ nullif(T5.NODECUSTCOUNT, 0)  AS CALLRATE

FROM CVKOMNZP.NZKOMUSER.NFOV_INBD_REMEDY_CALL_DETAILS  T1 
LEFT JOIN  
        ( 
                SELECT T2.NODE_CODE,T2.BEGIN_DATE,T2.END_DATE,T2.HOUSE,T2.CORP
                FROM CVKOMNZP.NZKOMUSER.D_HOUSEHOLD_CH_HIST T2  
        ) T3 
ON  T1.CORP = T3.CORP AND T1.HOUSE = T3.HOUSE AND (T1.CALL_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN T3.BEGIN_DATE AND T3.END_DATE) 

LEFT JOIN  
        ( 
                SELECT count(ADM_HOUSEHOLD_ID) AS NODECUSTCOUNT,NODE_CODE,BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE
                FROM CVKOMNZP.NZKOMUSER.D_HOUSEHOLD_CH_HIST
                WHERE HOUSE_STATUS_CODE = 2  
                    AND END_DATE = '2999-12-31 00:00:00'
                    AND T1.CALL_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN BEGIN_DATE AND END_DATE
                GROUP BY NODE_CODE,BEGIN_DATE,END_DATE

        ) T5 
ON  T5.NODE_CODE = T3.NODE_CODE  AND T1.CALL_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN T5.BEGIN_DATE AND T5.END_DATE

WHERE T1.EXCLUSION_FLAG = 'N' 
        AND T1.CALL_TIMESTAMP >= To_Date ('07-29-2017', 'MM-DD-YYYY' ) AND T1.CALL_TIMESTAMP <= To_Date ('07-31-2017', 'MM-DD-YYYY' )

GROUP BY 
    to_char(T1.CALL_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-IW')
    ,T3.NODE_CODE
    ,T5.NODECUSTCOUNT
    ,T1.CALL_CATEGORY_LVL_3
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to show sample data, current results and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this right, you want to get a COUNT without grouping by BEGIN and END DATE. However, because your Subquery (2nd LEFT JOIN) needs to include the BEGIN and NEED, you do not know how to group without it.

If this is the case, you'll need a subquery for your count and JOIN it back to the same table.

FYI: Your T1.CALL_TIMESTAMP does not make sense in this subquery since you don't have a table called T1. I renamed it to "a". Feel free to change it to what you want.

See if this make sense

```
LEFT JOIN  
    ( 
            SELECT a.BEGIN_DATE, 
                   a.END_DATE, 
                   node.NODECUSTCOUNT, 
                   a.node_code

            FROM CVKOMNZP.NZKOMUSER.D_HOUSEHOLD_CH_HIST a

             /**Subquery to get a COUNT of all the Node based on NODE_CODE. 
              You link this back to your query above using the NODE CODE**/
            JOIN ( SELECT count(ADM_HOUSEHOLD_ID) AS NODECUSTCOUNT,
                        NODE_CODE
                     FROM CVKOMNZP.NZKOMUSER.D_HOUSEHOLD_CH_HIST
                     GROUP BY NODE_CODE ) node on node.node_code = a.node_code

                WHERE a.HOUSE_STATUS_CODE = 2  
                AND a.END_DATE = '2999-12-31 00:00:00'
                AND a.CALL_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN BEGIN_DATE AND END_DATE

   ) ..JOIN THIS BACK TO YOUR MAIN TABLE
```

Comment: That was it, I am getting slightly higher numbers because of the sub join, but I can figure that one out. Thank you for the quick response and the answer.